# Fail to pick up Hibernate default schema

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to get some data from Two tables from oracle database. 
I define `MyEntity` class which uses annotations(Only use `@Entity` without using `@Table` when defining the class). The hibernate for this entity looks like the codes below:

```
public List<MyEntity> getAll() {
    return oracleSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
           .createSQLQuery("SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column1" +
                    "FROM A_table a JOIN B_table b " +
                    "ON a.column1 = b.column1")
            .addEntity(MyEntity.class).list();
}
```

I have set up the default schema property of hibernate.`default_property` in the datasource of persistence file. However, this does not work with the errors like this:

`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

When i just add my hard code into the sql query like below, the program works fine.

`"SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column1 FROM myschema.A_table a JOIN myschema.B_table b ON a.column1 = b.column1"`,

How can i enable my program to pick up the default setting?

Answer (score 0):

Add annotations to your entities:

```
@Table(schema="myschema")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add in hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: Check is name of class "MyEntity" which you annotated as @Entity same as name of table  in your database??

Comment: The class of `MyEntity` contains only select fields required from two existing tables. The correspond table does not exist. However, when i add schema name in the sql query of `List<MyEntity> getAll()` method in hibernate, it works. That is the wired point.